# Enabling viper-mode and vimpulse in compilation-mode

Tags: emacs, viper-mode, viper, vimpulse

viper.el is [hardcoded](http://repo.or.cz/w/emacs.git/blob/HEAD:/lisp/emulation/viper.el#l408) to disable `viper` in `compilation-mode`. How can I fix this without modifying the original file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really** want to do this, you should be able to customize the variable `viper-emacs-state-mode-list` and remove `compilation-mode`.

Comment: Yes, I really want to. I can't stand getting trapped in a compilation window where all my shortcuts stop working. I can add my own mappings.

Comment: @Natan Yellin - fair enough - so, did you try to customize the variable? It seems to work for me.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick: `(setq viper-emacs-state-mode-list ())`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running "M-x viper-mode"?  That's what I do when I end up in a buffer in which it has been disabled, or at least not enabled.